# How to make a calculation module (mathematics) in JS?

Tags: javascript, math

I am new to stackoverflow and ask you to bear with me. I need to make a mathematical calculation in JavaScript where it will always return me the difference between the two variables. In math would look like this:

```
a = 10;
b = 5;

a-b = 5;
b-a = -5;

|a-b| = 5; /*need this*/
|b-a| = 5; /*need this*/
```

how do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript features a built-in object that exposes foundamental math functions: `Math`.
See the MDN [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math), or the [ECMAScript reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8).

As to your question:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 5;
var res = Math.abs(a-b);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use **[`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)** to get the absolute value.

`Math.abs(4-5)` => `1`